# Rewrite third party project using rewrite-maven-plugin

Tags: openrewrite, rewrite-maven-plugin

I have a Maven Multimodule project and one method in the code of a third-party library I need to rewrite.
What I do is unpack the `sources.jar` of that project to `target/generated-sources/3rdparty/` followed by the `build-helper-plugin` to add this folder as source directory.

So far so good.Next step is to write a recipe.

There are a couple of things I noticed: there doesn't seem to be a goal I can call just scoped to this module. If I bind `runNoFork` to the `generate-sources` phase, it is scanning all modules.
Also, it seems that this plugin doesn't use the sourcedirectories from a Maven project, hance these files are not detected. Is this a bug or is there something I can configure to scan this directory?

Answer (score 1):

Good seeing you here! We unfortunately don't yet support `build-helper-plugin`. It's come up a couple months ago, but I hadn't had time to look into it so far. It sounds like we should indeed adopt the source directories you mention and work that into [openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin). Welcome to open an issue and we'll see what we can do.

Do I understand your use case correctly in that you want to take the source jar of an existing 3rdparty library, modify that with a recipe, and use the modified sources in your own project? Just so I have the use case straight and can think through any alternative solutions.

Also: know that you're always welcome to reach out if there's any way in which I can help. We have a public Slack, issues, and predictable first name email addresses at moderne.io.

Comment: Hi Tim, that's indeed the usecase. And I want it to be part of the buildlifecycle. The current code wants to read config from a properties-file on the classpath, I want to externalize that. The rewrite needs to kick in just before compilation. If that requires a change in the plugin, I can help improving it.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable and achievable goal, provided we indeed get build-helper working in the plugin. Happy to help explore that. Slight word of caution that OpenRewrite isn't always quick if the 3rdparty library is big. Something to factor in.

Comment: I'm facing the very same issue, has a ticket already been created for this?

Comment: Thanks for logging an issue! Providing the link here for others as well
https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin/issues/755